# LSTM does not predict outputs having been trained with one-hot-encoded dataframe

Tags: lstm, one-hot-encoding, multivariate-time-series

I try to apply a multivariate forecasting on a df like this:

[initial dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t85wm.png)

I transformed the dataset to one-hot-encoding to feed it to an LSTM

```
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
```

```
results = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(cal_automn)
```

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(results)
```

```
df_results.columns = one_hot_encoder.get_feature_names(df.columns)
```

```
df_results
```

[df_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7BZQ.png)

It seems to be ok then I try to preprocess the data to enter the LSTM.

```
def prep_data(df, window_size = 5):
    df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
    X = [] # x shape will be the number of training examples by the number of time steps we are using times  the number of variables we are using 
    y = []
    for i in range(len(df_as_np) - window_size): # iterate through the dataframe with an index 
        row = [r for r in df_as_np[i:i + window_size]]
        X.append(row)
        label = [df_as_np[i + window_size][0], df_as_np[i + window_size][1]] # we want to predict the whole next row "the next day"
        y.append(label)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

I have consecutive day inputs of a string and a float, specifically training my LSTM model I want to predict the next day of the data frame, an output like this

```
2021-12-1    Z    86400.0 (Z: the event type, 86400.0: the duration of the event type in seconds)
```

Then I split my data:

```
X2, y2 = prep_data(df_results) #2 the number of input values 
X2.shape, y2.shape #((2452, 5, 291), (2452, 2))

X2_train, y2_train = X2[:2000], y2[:2000]
X2_val, y2_val = X2[2000:2100], y2[2000:2100]
X2_test, y2_test = X2[2100:2452], y2[2100:2452]

X2_train.shape, y2_train.shape, X2_val.shape, y2_val.shape, X2_test.shape, y2_test.shape
#((2000, 5, 291), (2000, 2), (100, 5, 291), (100, 2), (352, 5, 291), (352, 2))
```

I define, compile, fit, the model :

```
model1 = Sequential()
#model1.add(Masking(mask_value=" ", input_shape=(6, y2)))
#model1.add(LSTM(lstm_units))
#model1.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(max_sequence_length, num_chars)))
model1.add(InputLayer((5,291)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(2, 'sigmoid')) # outputs 2 things
model1.summary()

cp1 = ModelCheckpoint('model1/', save_best_only=True)

model1.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy', 'RootMeanSquaredError']) # loss= 'binary_crossentropy'

model1.fit(X2_train, y2_train, validation_data=(X2_val, y2_val), epochs=10, callbacks=[cp1])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecay1.png)

Tha accuracy is very bad.. however I continue..

And assuming the model has learned something I try to check it on the test set

```
model1.predict(X2_test.all(), y2_test.all())
```

However when I do that i get error

`ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.bool_'>, <class` [`model results`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecay1.png)`'NoneType'>`

Further when I try to plot and add all the results by creating a df with the model results I get an empty df and plot.  [plot visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtblL.png)

Do you have any idea on what is the problem, I understand it has to do with the hot-encoded initial df.. but not sure

Comment: I run again the script and with same input it gave me accuracy 0.9915, i dont understand why it does that. (it has happened 2-3 times). However the model1.predict(X2_test.all(), y2_test.all()) still doesnt work